# Does the first column of a composite INDEX need another index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

We have the following table in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_team` (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`team_id`),
    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

IS `KEY user_id (user_id)` required here? I remember reading somewhere saying the first column of a composite index has an index automatically.  Can't seem to find the source.

Comment: Can a "user" be on multiple "teams"?  If not, I quibble with the PK.  And the need for the table.

Answer (score 5):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

Using your example index of `(user_id, team_id)`, a query filtering only on `user_id` can use this index because the B-tree is first indexed on this field.  That it also splits afterwards by `team_id` doesn't really matter, because you are only looking for all records matching or not matching a certain `user_id` value or values.

Now if you wanted to also support queries which filter only on the `team_id`, then you would need to add at least one other index.  In this case, your current composite index would not cover this type of query.

Answer (score 3):

`KEY (user_id)` is totally redundant with the primary key.  The primary key also creates an index.  A composite index with multiple columns is also an index for each sequence of leading columns.  So, an index on `(a, b, c)` is also an index on `(a)` and `(a, b)`.

MySQL documentation actually has a good explanation of multi-column indexes.  You might want to check [it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) out.